# Subscribing multiple installations to a channel

Tags: parse-platform

I have a list of parse installations for push notifications.
I would like to add those installations to a channel, so that I can target the push notifications to those channels.

I see that it can be done like so:

```
   curl -X PUT 

   -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: application_id"
   -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: rest_api_key"
   -H "X-Parse-Session-Token: session_token"
   -H "Content-Type: application/json"

   {
    "deviceType": "ios",
    "deviceToken": "0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef",
    "channels": {"__op":"AddUnique","objects":["foo"]}
   }
```

https://api.parse.com/1/installations/installation_object_id

But I store the installationId on my system, not the objectId. Would one be able to perform this same operation using only the installation IDs? Perhaps using a query.